# Automapper mapping classes with different types of the same base class

Tags: c#, automapper-3

I know this sounds like a duplicate but actually I couldn't find anything about the specific topic, so please read it first before you judge :-)

I want to use automapper to copy information from a pretty big class structure that I do not have under my control. Interfaces and classes cannot be changed by me.

Consider this structure as a well known working pattern first:
Source:

```
[DataMember]
[ProtoMember(4)]
public List<Journey> Journeys = new List<Journey>();
```

Destination:

```
[XmlArray("Journeys")]
[DataMember]
[XmlArrayItem("InventoryJourney", typeof (InventoryJourney), Namespace = "http://my.schema.com/msg.journey")]
public MsgList<InventoryJourney> Journeys
{
  get
  {
    if (this._journeys == (MsgList<InventoryJourney>) null)
      this._journeys = new MsgList<InventoryJourney>();
    return this._journeys;
  }
  set
  {
    this._journeys = value;
  }
}
```

InventoryJourney is a direct inheritation from Journey class. As the interface clearly shows which types to create, Automapper handles that correctly. The destination will contain objects of type InventoryJourney.

Now to my problem:

The mentioned InventoryJourney class needs to have a property populated that is defined in the base class Journey, looks like this:

Destination:

```
public MsgList<Segment> Segments
```

Source:

```
public List<Segment> Segments = new List<Segment>();
```

The signature of this property looks like Segment classes shall be contained, but actually this list contains classes of type InventorySegment that is a direct inheritation of Segment class.

Is it possible to configure AutoMapper in a way that it creates a certain derived type instead of the base type defined by the property?

My current configuration looks like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Source.Segment, Destination.Segment>()
    .Include<Source.Segment, Destination.InventorySegment>();
Mapper.CreateMap<Source.Segment, Destination.InventorySegment>();
```